# How to force the infinite while loop script to stop in sql server agent jobs

Tags: sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I created the following job to run the stored procedure every 5 second in the Sql Server Agent. I tried to stop the job but the script seems still running. Is there a way that I can stop the job?

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
     execute sp_TPAC_ETL_Create_Stamping_Transactions
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05.000';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have an infinite loop with a 5 second delay, and then you relaunch this query every 5 seconds with a job as well?  If you only want it to run every 5 seconds remove the loop and keep the job.

If you've stopped your job, you can stop the individual looping queries in this way.

Open / Run SSMS and connect to the server in question. Change to use the correct database in SSMS, run SP_Who2. This gives you a list of all connections, and their state. Take any one connection SPID#; you can kill the connection by issuing KILL SPID#.

If for some reason you cannot use kill, or you simply have too many instances running to kill them one at a time, you can restart your server to stop the queries.